# How to render images in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, opengl-es

I am new in the field of iphone development.

I want to render two images with the help of openGL one over the other the first image act as background and on the second image when the user touches then a method will execute.

Please help me out how to render these images.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself (if so, show some code)? Do you know OpenGL programming, or are you just beginning?

Comment: ya i am just a beginner i dont know even the abc of open GL 

please help!!!